# Floating ghost CSS animation

Tags: css, svg, css-animations

I have created an SVG ghost for my website's logo. I have made a CSS animation so when a user hovers the logo, the ghost starts floating.

Everything works okay except that when it is unhovered, the ghost just drops back to it's original position. Is it possible to have it also animated when it returns to `translateY(0)`? I have tried a solution myself, but it doesn't work.

Here is the example:

```css
@keyframes float {
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-8px);
  }
}
@keyframes bob {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-8px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
@keyframes sink {
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
#logo svg {
  margin: 20px;
  overflow: visible;
}
#logo #ghost {
  animation-name: sink;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
#logo:hover #ghost {
  animation-name: float, bob;
  animation-duration: 0.3s, 0.7s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out, ease-in-out;
  animation-delay: 0s, 0.3s;
  animation-direction: normal, alternate;
  animation-iteration-count: 1, infinite;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

```html
<div id="logo">
  <svg width="100" height="100">
    <g id="ghost">
      <rect fill="red" width="100" height="100" />
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: A Demo would be useful - See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: To my knowledge... this isn't possible with css animations. For example... if you were to make some animation that faded through rainbow colors on hover... and then you pulled away--- how would it know how to get back the original color? I believe this is a more complex function, and I would suggest javascript and maybe a library like velocity.js to help.

Comment: I have added a demo to the question.

Comment: Here was my take:  http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/rVGemK?editors=110

Comment: Thank you for your help @sheriffderek. Your example works great, however it doesn't exactly what I'm trying to implement. My ghost doesn't always float infinitely, only when it is hovered. It is also an inline SVG, so I can't use properties like position for a <g> element.

Comment: I knew it wasn't what you really wanted... but it was fun. : ) BTW you can totallly put your SVG in a div and move that... and - you can pretty much animate any part of the svg as well. Just give the `<g class='ghost-head'>` `<path class='left-eye'>` etc...  ( in my experience )

Comment: Indeed it was. :D My SVG already has a container, but only one group of it animates, the other groups contain my logo text which have no animation, that's why it is so complicated. And yes, I can give ids and classes to groups, like I did with #ghost but they can only be animated with transforms, and not positioning. Do you have any suggestions on how it would be possible with javascript (jQuery)?

Comment: This is how I would do it with velocity.js --- but as you'll see - it's needs some timers and to clear intervals:  http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/vOeGMK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't all that difficult with JQuery.

Here's a function that can be called regularly with a `setInterval()` timer:

```
var haunt=function(){
  var dy;
  ghost_ticks++;
  ghost_clock++;
  if (ghost_clock>30) ghost_clock=30;
  dy = Math.sin(Math.abs(ghost_clock) * Math.PI/60);   /* sine wave */
  dy *= -40 + 6*Math.cos(ghost_ticks/5);               /* ramp      */
  $("#ghost").css("transform","translate(0,"+dy+"px)");
  if (ghost_clock==0) {
    clearInterval(ghost_timer);
    ghost_timer=ghost_ticks=0;
  }
}
```

This calculates the ghost's position as the sum of two components — a sine-wave hovering motion, and a vertical offset that ramps up and down at the start and end of the animation and also controls the amplitude of the hovering.

This is done with two counter variables: `ghost_ticks` simply increments at every tick and is used to calculate the hovering position, while `ghost_clock` controls the ramp by counting up to 30 and then stopping. At the end of the animation, its value is made negative, so it counts back to zero, at which point the animation stops.

You can still use a CSS transition to change the ghost's colour.

```js
var ghost_ticks=0, ghost_clock=0, ghost_timer=0;
var haunt=function(){
  var dy;
  ghost_ticks++;
  ghost_clock++;
  if (ghost_clock>30) ghost_clock=30;
  dy = Math.sin(Math.abs(ghost_clock) * Math.PI/60);
  dy *= -40 + 6*Math.cos(ghost_ticks/5);
  $("#ghost").css("transform","translate(0,"+dy+"px)");
  if (ghost_clock==0) {
    clearInterval(ghost_timer);
    ghost_timer=ghost_ticks=0;
  }
}
var start_haunting=function(){
  if (ghost_clock < 0) ghost_clock = -ghost_clock;
  if (!ghost_clock) ghost_timer=setInterval(haunt,25);
};
var stop_haunting=function(){
  if (ghost_clock > 0) ghost_clock = -ghost_clock;
};
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#logo").hover(start_haunting,stop_haunting);
});
```

```css
#logo { background-color:#000; width: 200px; height: 200px; }
#logo #ghost { fill:#333; transition: fill 1s; }
#logo:hover #ghost { fill:#999; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="logo">
  <svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
    <g id="ghost" stroke="none">
      <path d="M60 160V100A40 40 0 0 1 140 100V160l-10-10l-10 10l
               -10-10l-10 10l-10-10l-10 10l-10-10ZM73 100a10 10 0
               0 0 20 0 10 10 0 0 0 -20 0M107 100a10 10 0 0 0 20
               0 10 10 0 0 0 -20 0z" />
      </g>
   </svg>
</div>
```